# ERROR: tag handler class for "rich:modalPanel" (org.richfaces.taglib.ModalPanelTag) was not found on the Java Build Path

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I am trying richface 4. It seems tags class are not setting on JAVA build path. I am getting this error for all rich component: "ERROR: tag handler class for * (org.richfaces.taglib.*) was not found on the Java Build Path"

For a4j component also, for all component i am getting same error "The tag handler class for "a4j:*" (org.ajax4jsf.taglib.html.jsp.*) was not found on the Java Build Path"

For richface4, i performed following actoin:

1) Added following jars:

```
annotations-4.0.0.Final.jar
cssparser-0.9.5.jar
guava-r08-gwt.jar
guava-r08.jar
jsf-api.jar
jsf-impl.jar
richfaces-components-api-4.1.0.Final.jar
richfaces-components-ui-4.1.0.Final.jar
richfaces-core-api-4.1.0.Final.jar
richfaces-core-impl-4.1.0.Final.jar
sac-1.3.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-digester-2.1-sources.jar
commons-digester-2.1.jar
commons-discovery-0.4.jar
jhighlight-1.0.jar
jsf-facelets-1.1.14.jar
```

web.xml is default generated and NO new element is added. As it is not required to change in RF4 (which is required in RF3.3).

JSP file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"  xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page language="java"
        contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" />
    <jsp:text>
        <![CDATA[ <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> ]]>
    </jsp:text>
    <jsp:text>
        <![CDATA[ <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> ]]>
    </jsp:text>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>TESTING</title>
</head>
<body>
<f:view>
<h:form>
<a4j:commandLink
     value="Opss! I forgot password"
     reRender="forgetPasswordPanel"
     oncomplete="#{rich:component('forgetPasswordPanel')}.show()">
</a4j:commandLink>                       
</h:form>
<rich:modalPanel id="forgetPasswordPanel" autosized="true" width="380">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Reset Password"/>
     </f:facet>
</rich:modalPanel>
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
</jsp:root>
```

i further investigated this issue and found that taglib(tld file) doesn't contain tag-class for many rich and a4j component and richFace4.1 jar does not have corrosponding java class for them (which is in richFaces 3.3 jars).

Am i missing some jars ? What else should i do to work with richface4 ?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to upgrade a RichFaces 3.3 web application to RichFaces 4.1. You need to do many more changes than only replacing the JAR files. You can find the exact migration steps in their own documentation: [RichFaces 3.3.x to 4.x migration guide](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration).

For example, JSP is been deprecated and replaced by Facelets, you'd need to rewrite your JSPs to be XHTMLs. The `<rich:modalPanel>` is been replaced by `<rich:popupPanel>`, you need to find and replace all those tags accordingly. The `reRender` attribute is been replaced by `update` attribute. Etcetera. Also that `jsf-facelets-1.1.14.jar` which is of Facelets 1.x should be removed from the `/WEB-INF/lib`. JSF 2.x libraries already ships with the right Facelets 2.x implementation bundled.

#### See also:

- [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0)